# How to fetch all record type Names for a object in LWC without APEX

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, record-type

I have 3 record Types in the Account object - USA, EUROPE, and ASIA. I want to show these record-type Names in LWC without apex. So, I am writing this code but somehow, I am not getting any results in the console.log.

Please Help.

**JS**

```javascript
import { LightningElement, track, wire, api } from 'lwc';
import { getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import ACCOUNT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Account';

export default class CreateContact extends LightningElement {

    @track statusOptions;
    @track value;
    @api objectApiName;

    @track objectInfo;
    @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: ACCOUNT_OBJECT}) objectInfo;

    TEST(){
        let recordtypeinfo = [];
        
        recordtypeinfo = JSON.stringify(this.objectInfo.data.recordTypeInfos);
        recordtypeinfo.forEach(rt => {
            console.log(rt);
                });
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you have to do is use **lightning/uiObjectInfoApi** module whose **getObjectInfo**  adaptor returns you all the info about object:-

```javascript
import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import { getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import ACCOUNT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Account';

export default class RecordFormWithRecordType extends LightningElement {
    // Flexipage provides recordId and objectApiName
    @api recordId;
    @api objectApiName;

    @track objectInfo;

    @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: ACCOUNT_OBJECT })
    objectInfo;

    GetrecordTypeInfo() {
        // Returns a map of record type Ids 
        const rtis = this.objectInfo.data.recordTypeInfos;
        Object.keys(rtis).forEach(element => {
           console.log(rtis[element].name);
        });
    }
}
```

Use **[getObjectInfo](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_wire_adapters_object_info)** wire adapter to get metadata about a specific object. The response includes metadata describing the object’s fields, child relationships, record type, and theme.

The problem with your code was :-

1. You were trying to run foreach loop on a stringify element by doing this `JSON.stringify(this.objectInfo.data.recordTypeInfos);` instead you should have use `let recordtypeinfo = this.objectInfo.data.recordTypeInfos;` Even you can directly iterate on it, you need to convert it to array.
2. So basically [JSON.stringify()](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp) Convert a JavaScript object into a string, hence even if you have initialized **recordtypeinfo** variable with empty array, later you assigned a stringify value which is not iterable.
3. The recordtypeinfo returns us this kind of structure:-

> ```json
> {
>     "012000000000000AAA": {
>         "available": true,
>         "defaultRecordTypeMapping": true,
>         "master": true,
>         "name": "Master",
>         "recordTypeId": "012000000000000AAA"
>     }
> }
> ```

Basically we had to convert in iterable format using [object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) which returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property names, iterated in the same order that a normal loop would.

Comment: Hi Sanket, thank you for the response. I understood and tried your code it still did not work. I put my code in the try-catch block and got this error - "TypeError: this.objectInfo.data.recordTypeInfos.forEach is not a function". Any Idea why is so?

Comment: I have made some edit. Please try now

Comment: OMG.. It worked. But why did we loop through keys? I mean it's same as what we written before because before the element was containing all the information including name. Can you please help understand? Also Add in the Answer please. Thank you.

Comment: I have tried explaining that as well. Basically the structure is complex, hence we have to use object.keys to convert into iterable array.

Comment: My bad, I missed your point number 3. I got it now. Thank you very much. Please add your Answer. :)